# Edgemarc 4552 DSL & T1 at the same time?

Tags: networking

I have an Edgemarc 4552 Router with 4 T1 inputs and a single DSL input.  Can both T1 and DSL be connected to the same Router?

Answer (score 0):

This device does not seem to support two connections at the same time.  Only one or the other.  No load balance or failover seems possible